# Hibernate Select query with a critera

Tags: mysql, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Here i am creating a hibernate query. The query is for selection of some ID form a table, as i want to add the criteria that have a not equal to and a equal to condition.The given query always return a unique value..
        how can i build the query in hibernate using criteria

ID | ST_NAME| EDU_ID

```
 1 STD E1

 2 STU E1

 3 STD E2

 4 STV E2


select ID from Table where EDU_ID = E1 and ST_NAME <>STD;
```

how can i make the query in hibernate?
Result i want is **2**

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create the Entity student. Then you can use the entity in Criteria API to get the desired results

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("eduId", "E1");
criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("name", "STD");
Student result = criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

With HQL: query seems like this:

```
select s.id from Student s where s.name!=? and s.edu=?
```

You have to pass student *name* and *edu* as parameter. If you are using Criteria API, [Pratik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303680/pratik)'s answer seems right.

Comment: select s.ID from table  where ug.testID =:testID and checkID !=checkID its not working properly.could u plz check with my query

Answer (score 1):

I got the result at last. its working perfectly with not equal to checking

```
select stuID from Table T where T.eduID =:eduID and stuName !=:stuName
```